# using str_replace to update value in double nested array

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to change the value in an array of an array using simple `str_replace()`

goal is to target `'value'`'s value and change it from `'male'` to `'female'`.

```
<?php

$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'mycustom',
    'meta_key' => 'last_name',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'nopaging' => true,
    'cache_results' => false,
    'update_post_meta_cache' => false,
     'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'gender',
            'value' => 'male',
            'compare' => 'EXISTS'

        )
    )
);
$args = str_replace(('meta_query'[0][1]),'female',$args, $i);
print_r($args);
?>
```

what isnt working in `$args = str_replace(('meta_query'[0][1]),'female',$args, $i);`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why dont you use this, try to find the right path and insert a new value. Like here:

`$args['meta_query'][0]['value'] = 'female';`

Inserting a new value instead of using `str_replace()`

**Explanation:** `str_replace` is used to change a part of a **string**, you are working with nested **arrays**. 
 To change a value in an array, you can select it like above and just give it an other value using `=`

Answer (score 1):

Your solution isn't working, because [`str_replace`](http://php.net/manual/function.str-replace.php) does not work with nested arrays (and your search string `'meta_query[0][2]'` is invalid).

So while you could change the order from `'ASC'` to `'DESC'` with str_replace, you would need to call str_replace recursivly on your array if you want to target nested array values.

[C Travel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25991803/353907) has posted a working solution